# Visual Studio 2008, no longer see the Refresh item on right click

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

I used to be able to right click Folders in my project and click 'refresh' to refresh the files within them, I don't see the option to do this any more, how do I fix it? The same thing has happened at work and at home.. has it always been like this and have I gone  insane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have the option. You might be able to get it back by [customizing the context menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/01/30/did-you-know-you-can-customize-the-commands-on-the-context-menus.aspx). Refresh is under Commands > View in the Customize dialog.

Comment: Thanks, sorted it on my work machine and will do on my home machine later today!

Answer (score 0):

The refresh icon is at the top of the solution explorer for me, does the job